# Time lag of loading local images in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, caching, ios5, uiwebview

I'm an appreneur creating iPhone apps, doing everything but coding which is outsourced. I'd appreciate some technical guidance on the following iOS 5 implementation of a simple utility app.

There is a custom-built rich text field where users can input images (stored locally, small size: 40x44 points) and text. This is implemented as `UIWebView`. With the current implementation, each time after an image is tapped, it appears after 1.5-2 sec delay (too long). After it's entered once, it's cached and next time it appears almost immediately.

Is it reasonable that such small images would take up to 2 sec to appear? Are there any efficient ways of reducing this time lag for non-cached images? Any tips would be very welcome. If there is any smart way of implementing this other than using `UIWebView`, it would also help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by tapped? You tap on a thumbnail and then a big version loads?

Comment: You tap on a 62x57 image (shown in a virtual keyboard), and its smaller version (40x44) appears in the rich text field. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using base64 embed images in your webview. it will cause the webview to load the image like text almost immediately.

Take a look at the link below for converting your image to Base64: http://www.dailycoding.com/Utils/Converter/ImageToBase64.aspx

and for using it in your html:
http://danielmclaren.com/2008/03/embedding-base64-image-data-into-a-webpage

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Shahin! I'll investigate this option.

Comment: You are so welcome Tetyana. Hope it help solving your problem :)